# Javascript that changes specific href link to new one? (no jquery)

Tags: javascript

Friends, can you give me simple javascript that will change href link with new one on all posts in my blogger blog.

```
<a href="http://domainone.com/brb.php">
```

to become

```
<a href="http://domaintwo.com/brb.php">
```

the problem is that domainone is no longer available and I need a mass change when user asks for this domain to be directed to the new one.

please no jquery only oldschool javascript.

Regards!

Comment: What have you tried so far? **"can you give me simple javascript**" This is not a free writing service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.setAttribute()`, something like this:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
   if(links[i].getAttribute('href') && links[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('domainone') >=0 )
    links[i].setAttribute('href', 'http://domaintwo.com/brb.php');
}
```

```html
<a href="http://domainone.com/brb.php">link</a>
```

Comment: How can you do this with specific link http://domainone.com/brb.php, because like that it changes all hrefs in a tag in all page ?

Comment: what is the specific domain? is their an id associated with the element?

Comment: No, no ID only href domainone.com/brb.php

Comment: The problem is that I have this same href in multiple pages and can't edit them to add ID :(

Comment: Onle have to replace domainone.com with domaintwo.com? Can you make if statement in your code to match the href domainone.com and then change it to domaintwo.com, without ID ?

Comment: Please my friend, how will the code look like then?

Comment: I have a blog with same href link in every post. This link is domainone.com/brb . Now I can't edit all posts manually because they are a lot and I want to change that link with javascript so when a user click on this link (doesn't matter which post) to open a new link domainTWO.com/brb  The javascript code have to find from all href links in my posts this one that matches domainone.com/brb (the old one) and then change it to the new one - domainTWO.com/brb

Comment: I can't get it to work, I put it like that in the page to test, but not working. Am I doing it wrong ?

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
       if(links[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('domainone') >=0 )
        links[i].setAttribute('href', 'http://domaintwo.com/brb.php');
    }
    </script>
    <a href="http://domainone.com">link</a>

Comment: do I need some window.onload or how to copy it to work... skype to continue?

Comment: my skype: vijikey find me or give me yours to find you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you want to change All a tags href, Use it
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var tag of aTags) {
  tag.setAttribute('href','http://domaintwo.com/brb.php');
}

//If you want to change specific one, Use it.
var aTag = document.querySelector('#first');
aTag.setAttribute('href','https://stackoverflow.com//posts/45746835');
<a href="#" id="first">a</a>
<a href="#" id="second">b</a>
<a href="#" id="third">c</a>
```

Try This.

The important thing is using setAttribute

Comment: Note that `NodeList.forEach` is not in the current HTML5 specification, and [not many browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) support it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 How about for-loop? is it okay?

Comment: A for loop is okay. But other than that, your code will modified the entire URL instead of just the domain name.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Oh... I confused.. My mistake. I'll fix it.